# How to find two functions that are not big-oh of each other?

Tags: asymptotics

I am asked to find two functions that are not big-oh of each other.
Is it correct if I pick say $f(n)=2\sin (n)$ and $g(n)=1$? That way, $f$ will never always be greater than $g$.

Comment: You should pick functions that are positive (at least from a point on) And your general idea is OK, but you should make sure that $f(n) \ne O(g(n))$ and $g(n) \ne O(f(n))$, and you should presumably add proofs.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin n \in O(1)$. Note the arbitrary constant in the definition of $O$.

Answer (score 1):

Some people are picky about negative-valued functions. Here's one that will satisfy even picky people:
$$
f(n) = n,\qquad g(n)=\begin{cases}
n^2 &\text{if $n$ is even}\\
1 & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
There clearly isn't a constant $k$ for which $f(n)\le k\cdot g(n)$ eventually so $f$ isn't big-O of $g$ and in the same way we can see that $g$ isn't big-O of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

The sine function oscillates between 1 and -1 up to a constant factor. So it would be correct to say that the function is $O(1)$ if the function is used to describe the runtime complexity of an algorithm, i.e. a complexity which oscillates as input size goes from $1,2,3$ to ... You could use $AbsoluteValue(sin(x))$ for the negative... Or $Sin(x)+1$...